# Elements in list end up equal to the same value

Tags: python, list

As the title says. I have 2 functions, the main one creates a list of values and the other creates teh value that needs to be stored. Although the values in the list keep getting updated (all of them) to the most recent one. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
def get_next(next_params):
    
    for i in range (0, 1000000):
        for x in range(0, len(next_params)):
            if next_params[x] != 255:
                next_params[x] += 1
                break
            else:
                next_params[x] = 0
            
    return next_params

def thread_execution():
    
    #Variables
    params = []
    p = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    #Creats a list of parameters
    for i in range(0, 10):
        params.append(p)
        p = get_next(p)
        print(p)
    print(params)

thread_execution()
```

The Output is this:

```
[64, 66, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[128, 132, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[192, 198, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 9, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 75, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[128, 141, 91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[192, 207, 106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 18, 122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 84, 137, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[[128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [128, 150, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm trying to obviously get each value to be different in the list.

Comment: you only create 2 distinct lists in this example, `params` and `p`. so `params` just contains 10 references to `p`. it's the same list you keep updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you create one unique list `p`
- you save it in `params`
- you modify `p` in `get_next`, the same `p`, not a copy
- then you add it again in `params`
- then again and again

You have one unique list in all your process, you just put it multiple times in the main list.

You need to copy it

```py
def thread_execution():
    
    params = []
    p = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    for i in range(0, 10):
        params.append(p)
        p = get_next(list(p)) # using list creates a new list from the existing p
```

Comment: This has been killing me for hours. Feel like I should have known this. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to read this wonderful article: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). The problem in your current question is tackled in [Names and values: making a game board](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201308/names_and_values_making_a_game_board.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_next(next_params):
    for i in range(0, 1000000):
        for x in range(0, len(next_params)):
            if next_params[x] != 255:
                next_params[x] += 1
                break
            else:
                next_params[x] = 0
    return next_params

def thread_execution():
    params = []
    p = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    for i in range(0, 10):
        params.append(p[:])  # append a copy of p
        p = get_next(p)
        print(p)
    print(params)

thread_execution()
```

you are appending the same list `(p)` multiple times to the `params` list.

use`p[:]` when appending to `params`, you ensure that a copy of the `p` list is added to the `params` list. This way, each element in the `params` list will be a distinct list